# Provide additional headers during Client OAuth Account Linking

Tags: actions-on-google

The fulfilment, oauth authorization and token URLs provided to my Google Action are protected by Cloudflare Access, which requires some extra HTTP headers to be provided on each request. Is it possible to provide these?

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/identity/service-tokens/